# MySQL Trigger With select

Tags: mysql

Ok i have a table called motors. When something is inserted in to that table i want a trigger to run that pulls back the last row added to the table, get the fields id, description, partnum and then insert those fields in to a different table called latest.

how would i write this?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to create something yourself or you expect something you'll copypaste and forget forever?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER INSERT ON motors
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO latest (motor_id, motor_description, motor_partnum) 
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.description, NEW.partnum);
```

Although, I feel obligated to tell you that if you're just trying to generate a list of the most recent motors, it'll be easier to maintain if you just select the X newest motors from the motors table.

Comment: So if i read you right, NEW.id, NEW.description, NEW.partnum are the fields from the motor table after it is inserted?

Comment: The reason I ask is that the id field is an auto number and is not passed when the the table is inserted to.

Comment: Yes, just change the `.id`, `.description`, etc to match your actual field names